# How to centralize the left nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I having problems trying to centralize a bootstrap standard nav in a row.

```
<footer id="page_footer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <ul id="page_footer_links" class="nav nav-pills nav-center">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p id="page_footer_wordpress" class="text-center">Orgulhosamente movido com <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="A Semantic Personal Publishing Platform" rel="generator" target="_blank">WordPress</a>!!!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the complete fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpontin/bkpnrLo0/

I tried putting text-center and center-block. None worked. Even putting margin 0 auto or text-align: center didn't work.

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.nav-pills` list items have default floating behavior to left. So change it to `none` and display them in one line using `display: inline-block`.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkpnrLo0/3/)

```css
#page_footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
}
#page_footer .container {
  padding: 20px;
}
#page_footer_links {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#page_footer_wordpress {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-pills > li {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer id="page_footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul id="page_footer_links" class="nav nav-pills nav-center">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="page_footer_wordpress" class="text-center">Orgulhosamente movido com <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="A Semantic Personal Publishing Platform" rel="generator" target="_blank">WordPress</a>!!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Adapted the answer with media queries and everything ran fine! Thanks!